# After using 'use strict' this directive is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

After using 'use restrict' this directive is not working.

It's not even hitting after using function and 'use strict' its not working

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var appRoot = angular.module("app.top").directive('confirmOnExit', ['$location', 'ConfirmModal', '$timeout', function (location, ConfirmModal, $timeout) {

        return {
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                $scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                    var unbindChangeSuccess = $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current, e) {
                        $scope.DirtyForm = ($scope.componentAddForm.$dirty ? $scope.componentAddForm.$dirty : $scope.resourceForm.$dirty)
                        if ($scope.DirtyForm) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            alert('Route Changed')                         
                        } else {
                        };
                    });

                })
            }
        };
    }]);
})
```

Comment: I could be because you are not self invoking the function

Comment: How to do that;

Comment: What's the error in the console?

Comment: It seems you want to use an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression ([IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)) but you're not calling it (you're missing the call parenthesis at the end) : `(function () { /* ... your code ... */  })();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be a self invoking function:

```
(function () {
    var appRoot = angular.module("app.top").directive('confirmOnExit', ['$location', 'ConfirmModal', '$timeout', function (location, ConfirmModal, $timeout) {

        return {
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                $scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                    var unbindChangeSuccess = $scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current, e) {
                        $scope.DirtyForm = ($scope.componentAddForm.$dirty ? $scope.componentAddForm.$dirty : $scope.resourceForm.$dirty)
                        if ($scope.DirtyForm) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            alert('Route Changed')                         
                        } else {
                        };
                    });

                })
            }
        };
    }]);
})();
```

For more info check out [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript) post.